# Что нужно сделать, чтобы сайт загрузил javascript?

Tags: python, парсер, selenium

Пытаюсь достать книгу, так как в браузере читать совершенно неудобно. Написал скрипт, но он не загружает страницу полностью, до нужного мне тега, чтобы получить ссылку. С помощью selenium эмулирую загрузку, открывается браузер, визуально страница полностью прогружается, но нужный div все равно не ищется. Пишет, что не функционирует без javascript. Но ведь сайт прогружается, значит скрипты работают. Не понимаю в чем проблема.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time


ua = UserAgent()
userAgent = ua.random

browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument("--incognito")
options.add_argument("--nogpu")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1280,1280")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')


driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": userAgent})


def get_data(url):
    response = requests.get(
        url,
        headers={'user-agent': f'{userAgent}'}
    )
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
    links = soup.find_all('document-view-img__container')
    print(links)


for i in range(537):
    i += 1
    url = f'https://viewer.rusneb.ru/ru/000199_000009_02000012752?page={i}&rotate=0&theme=white'
    get_data(url)
    break


try:
    browser.get(url=url)
    time.sleep(10)
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
finally:
    browser.close()
    browser.quit()
```

Вручную все картинки уже давно нашел, мог бы скачать руками, но интересно сделать это автоматически средствами python

Comment: а не проче скачать файл в формате pdf и преобровать в удобный для вас формат?

Comment: А если ходите получать картинки с искомой страницы запрос выглядить по другому

Comment: @СергейШашко на сайте файл хранится не в pdf, а в виде картинок, закодированных в base64. Раскодировщик уже написал, он успешно работает с ссылкой, которую я копирую вручную из дебаг консоли браузера. Но картинок 500+ штук, поэтому решил спарсить, и если код вручную виден полностью, то парсер выдает только самое начало, а дальше сайт выводит ошибку, что без включенного javascript вьювер не доступен, и, соответсвенно, достать ссылку автоматически я не могу, она просто не загружается в html

Comment: В том до и дело что он хранится в формате pdf и что вы видете в браузере это результат работы скрипта JS над pdf. Еще раз повторяю,  если ходите получать картинки с искомой страницы запрос выглядить по другому.

Comment: @СергейШашко хм... Буду очень признателен, если вы поможете понять, как выцепить его в pdf. Уже несколько дней исследую код, но ни одного намека на наличие pdf не встретил... И, если конечно не затруднит, как выглядит запрос на извлечение картинок? Это уже для обучения и понимания на будущее

Comment: на сайте кнопка 'читать' и 'кнопка скачать PDF'

Comment: @СергейШашко а, для этого файла скачивание недоступно, поэтому не могу найти в коде ссылки на сам pdf. В запросах есть вот такое: "downloadAccess":{"isDownloadable":false,"downloadableFormats":[]

Comment: В браузере( в Firefox)  инстременты веб-разработчика вкладка сеть смотрим какие запросы отправляютя и что принемаеться

Comment: @СергейШашко именно там он и возвращает отдельные картинки, но цельного файла pdf там нет

Comment: Зто изначально pdf. сриптами JS преобразуется

Comment: В исходном  HTML есть ссылки на pdf не в явном виде

Comment: @СергейШашко вы подтолкнули ход моих мыслей в другую сторону. Попробую ещё более тщательно проследить за запросами и ответами сервера

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надеюсь разберетесь что чему

```
import requests

page = 0
while True:
    page +=1
    res = requests.get(f'https://viewer.rusneb.ru/api/v1/document/000199_000009_02000012752/page/{page}')
    if not (res.status_code == 200):
        break
    print(f'{page=}')

print('End')
```

Получить ссылку на скачивания pdf

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('https://rusneb.ru/catalog/000207_000017_RU_RGDB_BIBL_0000352301/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, "lxml")
ff = soup.find("a", class_="button button--full button--empty button--h52").get('href')
print(f'https://rusneb.ru{ff}')
```

Comment: но Онегина можно и так скачать. Если я изменю ссылку на свою, то: "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'"

Comment: на кaкую ссылку?

Comment: Пардон, если вставить ссылку на книгу (https://rusneb.ru/catalog/000199_000009_02000012752/), то pdf действительно скачивается, но пустой, 0 байт

Comment: И вот что получаю при анализе запросов и ответов для страницы книги в консоли firefox: "We're sorry but online-viewer-frontend-2 doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue."

Comment: Так кнопки скачать нету в браузере (она есть тока не активна)

Comment: поэтому я пытаюсь спарсить. Сами картинки я уже давно нашел, могу их вручную скачать, но качать 500 штук по одной - это неудобно. Но при парсинге уткнулся в то, что сайт просто не отдает в html код ссылки. Говорит, что нужны включенные javascript

Comment: А код в ответе первая половина для чего? Походу вы не разобрались.

Comment: не 500, a 537 картинок ))

Comment: Я действительно не понимаю, код просто показывает количество страниц. Что он мне еще может дать? Мой скрипт ходит по страницам. Но получает при этом неполную информацию. Вопрос то в этом

Comment: в место print(f'{page=}') напишите ваш код по обработке перемменой res (res и есть скачанная картинка)

Comment: Тысяча благодарностей!!! Это так просто, оказывается, я очень намудрил  с кодом! Спасибо, прекрасный человек!